# How do I detect if a bluetooth audio device is connected in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bluetooth, core-audio

I'm working on an application that plays audio on OsX. I'm able to list the available output devices with CodeAudio, but I have issues with a bluetooth headset; Even though the device is powered off and not connected, it's still listed in the OsX sound pref pane, and therefore picked up by CoreAudio as a valid output.
I'd like *not* to display bluetooth outputs if the corresponding device isn't connected already.

I've tried to check CoreAudio properties like those:

`kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsAlive`
`kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunning`
`kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere`

but there's no difference between the default output and the bluetooth output.

Is this kind of detection something doable with Coreaudio?

Comment: I'd like to know this too. You've probably seen this: http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2010/Oct/msg00171.html

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of future searchers the way I've done it in the past is to:

- Enumerate the detected devices
- Query the `kAudioDevicePropertyTransportType` property for each AudioDeviceID
  which will return a transport type ID constant.
- Match for the
  `kAudioDeviceTransportTypeBluetooth` or
  `kAudioDeviceTransportTypeBluetoothLE` type

That way you can determine the type of connection the device is using (USB, Firewire etc).  You can find the full list of transport types in `AudioHardwareBase.h`